# PHP include/require inside functions

Tags: php, function, optimization, include, require

Having functions that are quite big and they are loading every time the page is loaded, would be better to write `function foo(){ include(.../file_with_function's_code); return; }` to minimize the size of the functions script? Or it doesn't matter because when a function is loaded (but not executed) also is loaded the content even if it is into an include? Thank you.

(Edit: my question is not about if it's possible or not)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

While @Luceos answer is technically correct (the best kind of correct), it does not answer the question you asked, namely is doing this better, or do includes happen regardless of function calls?

I tested this in the most basic way (OP, why didn't you?):

```
<?php
echo "Testing...";

function doThing() {
    include nonExistantFile.php;
}
//doThing();
echo "Done testing.";
```

Results:

if I call `doThing();` I get a file not found warning.

If I comment out `doThing();`... there is no error! So you can save file load time by doing this.

Comment: Good question "why didn't you?", I really didn't think about that obvious test! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 12):

Or, as a good alternative, encapsulate your functions in classes, and take the benefit of [`__autoload`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) :

```php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}
```

Encapsulate `myBigFunction()` in a class

```php
class myBigFunction {
  public static function run() {
    //the old code goes here
  }
}
```

save it as `myBigFunction.php`

When you call the function as static method on the class :

```php
myBigFunction::run()
```

`__autoload` will load the file, but not before that.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. Splitting functions into individual files will cause a lot of extra confusion, and the many small files may actually make it *less* performant. Grouping functions into meaningful classes, on the other hand, helps you organise your code and maintain it as it grows.

Comment: I'm still not using classes, but I archive your suggestion to check it out! Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 6):

Yes that's possible; see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

> If the include occurs inside a function within the calling file, then
>   all of the code contained in the called file will behave as though it
>   had been defined inside that function. So, it will follow the variable
>   scope of that function.

Question is, why not add the surrounding function definition to that included file. I think the only viable reason to include within a function is to split code within that function into bits.

Comment: Yes, I know it is possible. My question is about optimization. Would be better to write an include inside a function in order to make it smaller? (Having functions that are quite big and they are loading every time the page is loaded). Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Both [Luceos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717181/luceos)' and [Albatrosz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000529/albatrosz) could be misread, so I felt that I should clarify these.

The **include** set of directives generate a *runtime* **ZEND_INCLUDE_OR_EVAL** operation which calls the Zend compiler to compile the referenced file.  So in general you ***should not*** embed include statements in a function, as:

- The include will be executed every time that code path is taken when the function is called.  Compiling the same bit of code 100s of times is a bad idea.
- If the code contains elements of global scope (e.g. function or class declarations) then executing that declaration even twice will cause compiler errors.

So ***don't*** unless you know what you are doing.  Use techniques such are those described by Albatrosz.  Incidentally his `__autoload()` function is just the sort of example of an exception where this is valid to do.

Comment: Not anymore. The function__autoload() is being DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php