# Does the body of my function get read every time?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a WordPress theme and trying to determine what is causing it to run so slowly. My`functions.php` is about 500 lines and has functions that interact with the database such as

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_N_more', 'get_N_more' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_N_more', 'get_N_more' );
$N = 9;
function get_N_more ( )
{
    global $wpdb, $N;
    $thisTable = ($_POST['workType'] === 'projs') ? 'wp_nas_projs' : 'wp_nas_cases';
    $q = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT id,compname,descsmall,sumsmall,imageurl FROM $thisTable ORDER BY postdate DESC LIMIT %d, %d",  intval($_POST['numItemsLoaded']), $N);
    $nextNRows = $wpdb->get_results($q);
    removeEscapes($nextNRows);
    $stillSomeLeft = ($_POST['numItemsLoaded'] + $N) < count($wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $thisTable")));
    // ^ would like more efficient way of doing above  
    die(json_encode(array('stillSomeLeft' => $stillSomeLeft, 'workItems' => $nextNRows)));
}
```

Such functions are not **called** every time the script is read, however I'm wondering if having them there in the first place could be creating performance slowdowns if PHP has read through them every time.

Comment: havent tried wordpress, but usually in order to execute a function, you need to call the function

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586313/php-include-require-inside-functions/21586547#21586547

Comment: Download and install the Query Monitor plugin and then look which queries are slowing the site down. Extremely useful plugin for debuuging issues related to slow sites and queries

Comment: Have you made any headway on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **maybe**.

- If you are calling `do_action(...)` several times on those actions you have added, then it could be the case that multiple ajax requests are being made and either are timing out or being cancelled as new requests are being issued.
- The main reason that you could have a very slow running page is that you are working directly with the database. If these are custom tables then there is a good probability that your indexes are not set correctly and the query is taking forever to return or is timing out.
- You should consider using get_posts or the WP_Query for posts or pages as you can then use the native wordpress functions to extract data. If you have made a custom post type then store your data in the post_meta and use wordpress core functions versus a secondary table.
- In general if your queries will be returning the same information on nearly every page load you might want to consider storing them to cache so you are not recalculating every page load.

What does all of this mean?

- Check your database table indexes. Run the query as it is built by your code in something like mysql workbench.
- Open up your browser console or firebug and look at the ajax requests being made when you load your pages.
- Check all the places you are calling do_action and adjust accordingly.
- When debugging print things to a file or to the screen. This will help tremendously.

Comment: @Mauro In all standard wordpress installs the functions.php file is processed so the short answer is YES. However you can add logic wraps around the functions for them not to execute for example; but the file itself is included in the Wordpress stack. The author however was asking if his specific logic was run everytime, and that would depend on if the hooks were being executed.

Answer (score 2):

PHP must only be reading your functions once during the request, therefore not causing a slowdown.

Look at the definition of your function:

```
function get_N_more ( )
{
}
```

It's not guarded in a check to [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/function_exists). This means that, if this file were parsed anywhere more than once, execution would fail and report an error that your `get_N_more` function is already declared in this scope.

The complexity and runtime efficiency of the code is never taken into account during parsing of the script, and 500 lines is a relatively trivial amount of code.

**tl;dr:** This isn't the cause of your slowdown.